# Why amdgpu-pro installs on Ubuntu 20.04.1 but not on Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1?

Tags: ubuntu-studio, opencl, amdgpu-pro

I tried to install amdgpu-pro on Ubuntu Studio to use Pro OpenCL (the included Open source amd OpenCl support is not good enough yet). After installation and reboot, I can see the login window, which looks normal, but after login there is only a blank white page showing up. But if I do the same with regular Ubuntu 20.04.1 (same kernel but not lowlatency)it works. I tried to alert about this but someone complained about not having to use amdgpu-pro. But if I want to do heavy video editing then having the Pro OpenCL version of the module is an advantage.

Comment: The Ubuntu Studio documentation mentions *low latency* kernel has some limitations, and there are *use cases* where you'll needed to use the provided *generic* kernel. Your issue is not with Ubuntu Studio, but the *low latency* kernel which is why Ubuntu Studio provides both.   *Sorry I can't find the blogged article about it, http://ubuntustudio.org/ is their web site (or usual Planet Ubuntu etc), but I remember reading about it working with Ubuntu News team*

Comment: I disagree with you. I installed the low latency kernel on the regular Ubuntu distro with amdgpu-pro and it's working. If I figure out why is not working on Ubuntu Studio, I'll post here...